# VK API Загрузка картинки из ссылки

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, post

У меня есть адрес для загрузки фото, который я получил следующим образом:

```
$upload_url =  json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer?access_token=".$token))->response->upload_url;
```

Теперь нужно передать картинку на адрес upload_url, сформировав POST-запрос с полем photo. Это поле должно содержать изображения в формате multipart/form-data.

Вопросы:
1) В каком виде нужно отправлять? В виде ссылки:

```
$photo_url = https://pp.userapi.com/c626231/v626231893/5cd94/ABCDEFG.jpg
```

Или файла:

```
$image_file = imagecreatefromjpeg ($photo_url);
```

?
Каким образом это сделать? 
Пытался сделать вот так:

```
$opts = array('http' => 
array( 
'method' => 'POST', 
'header' => 'Content-type: multipart/form-data', 
'photo' => $photo_url (пробовал как саму ссылку, так и файл)
) 
); 

$context = stream_context_create($opts); 
$result = file_get_contents($upload_url, false, $context);
```

Но ничего не вышло, в ответе $result приходил пустой массив photo[]. 
В чем может быть причина и как правильно поступить в данной ситуации?

Загружаю на сервер картинку:

```
copy($photo_url, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/img.jpg');
```

и пытаюсь загрузить с сервера:

```
'photo' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/img.jpg'
```

Но массив photo как был пустой так и остался :(

Comment: Не пробовал никогда stream_context_create. Загружал картинки при помощи curl, достаточно просто. Некоторые советуют guzzle

Comment: Использовал curl:

$ch = curl_init( $upload_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

Массив photo все еще пустой :с

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php достаточно простой пример вроде бы.